# Makefile - generic target rule with src- and obj-files in nested directories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have code sorted in nested directories like

```
src/cmn/abc.cpp
src/voc/xyz.cpp
```

And desired object output should be

```
obj/cmn/abc.o
obj/voc/xyz.o
```

The Makefile entries are

```
SRC_FILES := src/cmn/abc.cpp src/voc/xyz.cpp
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst %.cpp,*.o,$(patsubst src/%,obj%,$SRC_FILES))
```

The generic target rule is simple (too simple) and not working as desired. It creates the obj-files right next to the src-files as it misses pattern substitution. Further it misses directory creation (like `obj/voc`).

```
.cpp.o:
        @$(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

How should a target be defined to achieve the desired goals from above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using GNU make already (`patsubst`) you might as well use [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) which are much more powerful than suffix rules:

```
obj/%.o : src/%.c
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```